# Angularjs communication controllers in different views - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, controller

I need a tip how to connect two controllers in different views in Rails.
I have items and an Cart in my index, when I click on item in new tab and add item to cart I want to this item be added to cart wihout refreshing it.

```
app.controller('LineItemsController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$controller', 'LineItems',
    function($scope, $rootScope, $controller, LineItems) {
        $controller('CartsController', {
            $scope: $scope
        });

        $scope.fetchLineItems = function() {
            LineItems.get({
                cartId: cartId
            }).then(
                function(results) {
                    $scope.lineItems = results;
                },
                function(error) {}
            )
        };

        $scope.fetchLineItems();

        $scope.$on('scanner-started', function(event, args) {
            console.log("alert");
            $scope.fetchLineItems();
        });
    }
]);

app.controller('LineItemController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$controller', 'LineItem',
    function($scope, $rootScope, $controller, LineItem) {
        $controller('LineItemsController', {
            $scope: $scope
        });

        $scope.addItem = function() {
            new LineItem({
                itemId: window.Id
            }).create().then(
                function(results) {
                    $scope.linkUpdated = true;
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('scanner-started');
                },
                function(error) {
                    $scope.errors = true;
                    $scope.linkUpdated = false;
                }
            )
        };
    }
]);

app.factory('LineItem', ['railsResourceFactory',
    function(railsResourceFactory) {
        return railsResourceFactory({
            url: '/items/{{itemId}}/line_items',
            title: 'line_item'
        });
    }
]);

app.factory('LineItems', ['railsResourceFactory',
    function(railsResourceFactory) {
        return railsResourceFactory({
            url: '/carts/{{cartId}}/line_items',
            title: 'line_item'
        });
    }
]);
```

My code looks like this, I added $broadcast and $on but it works only on my show view, not index.

Is there something like $scope refresh or something like that which I can give to my index?

Answer (score 0):

you can crate simple service

```
yourApp.factory('someService', function() {
  var data = {};
  return {
    getData: function() {
      return data;
    },
    setData: function(value) {
      data = value;
    }
  };
});
```

Then set data in one controller:

```
someService.setData($scope.yourValue);
```

and then get this value from service:

```
someService.getData();
```

or implement `$wath` within function:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
   optimizerData.getData();
}, function(newValue) {
   console.log(newValue);  
});
```